# Check if user is already logged in

Tags: c#, google-api, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing an application for Windows Phone 8.1 which will use Google Blogger Api. For authorization I am using the **GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync()** function and everything is alright with that, I can do everything with my blog (get the blog/post lists, edit, delete, add posts ...).

When my application opens at first it calls **GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync()** function and in case when the user is already logged in (previously authenticated and authorized) the function returns and redirects to start page where I put the list of blogs. **This is fine for me.**

**My problem is:**
When the user is not logged in I want to open another page ('welcome' page) where I will have some basic info about my application and sign in button. When user clicks that button in that case only I want to call **GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync()** function which will redirect me to sign-in page. But I couldn't find method to check if the user is already logged in and only in that case show the 'welcome' page.

Here is how I am using **GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync()** function.

```
m_credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
  new ClientSecrets
  {
    ClientId = "my_client_id",
    ClientSecret = "my_client_secret"
  },
  new[] { BloggerService.Scope.Blogger },
  "user", CancellationToken.None);
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution of my problem and wanted to share it here it can be helpful for someone.

That's wonderful the Google API codes are open for everyone so I could dig inside the **GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync()** function and saw all steps it does. Here is the all steps that I could collect into one function

```
private static async Task<UserCredential> AuthorizeAsync()
{
  var initializer = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer 
  { 
    ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets 
    { 
      ClientId = Constants.ClientId,
      ClientSecret = Constants.ClientSecret
    },
    Scopes = new[] { BloggerService.Scope.Blogger }, 
    DataStore = new StorageDataStore() 
  }; 

  var flow = new AuthorizationCodeFlow(initializer); 
  var codeReceiver = new AuthorizationCodeBroker(); 
  var token = await flow.LoadTokenAsync("user", CancellationToken.None).ConfigureAwait(false); 
  if (token == null || (token.RefreshToken == null && token.IsExpired(flow.Clock))) 
  { 
    var redirectUri = codeReceiver.RedirectUri; 
    AuthorizationCodeRequestUrl codeRequest = flow.CreateAuthorizationCodeRequest(redirectUri); 
    var response = await codeReceiver.ReceiveCodeAsync(codeRequest, CancellationToken.None).ConfigureAwait(false); 
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(response.Code)) 
    { 
      var errorResponse = new TokenErrorResponse(response); 
      throw new TokenResponseException(errorResponse); 
    } 

    token = await flow.ExchangeCodeForTokenAsync("user", response.Code, codeReceiver.RedirectUri, 
                CancellationToken.None).ConfigureAwait(false); 
  } 
  m_credential = new UserCredential(flow, "user", token); 
  return m_credential;
}
```

The steps collected from different functions sequentially called by **GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync()** function. From code we can see this line

```
if (token == null || (token.RefreshToken == null && token.IsExpired(flow.Clock)))
```

which checks if the user is already authenticated or not. If yes it goes the next step else it authenticates the user. So I could write this simple function for me:

```
public async Task<bool> IsUserAuthenticated()
{
  var initializer = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer 
  { 
    ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets 
    { 
      ClientId = Constants.ClientId,
      ClientSecret = Constants.ClientSecret
    },
    Scopes = new[] { BloggerService.Scope.Blogger }, 
    DataStore = new StorageDataStore() 
  }; 

  var flow = new AuthorizationCodeFlow(initializer); 
  var codeReceiver = new AuthorizationCodeBroker(); 
  var token = await flow.LoadTokenAsync("user", CancellationToken.None).ConfigureAwait(false); 
  if (token == null || (token.RefreshToken == null && token.IsExpired(flow.Clock))) 
  { return false; } 
  else 
  { return true; }
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me what is `"user"` in `flow.LoadTokenAsync`?

Comment: The 'user' is the user name for which the tokens are generated. In my pc for example in the following path the file had been generated - C:\Users\ashotk\AppData\Roaming\Google.Apis.Auth\Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse-ashot. My user name is 'ashot' now If I change 'ashot' to another user it will ask credentials again and will save tokens in another file to use later.

Comment: Okay, I am getting problem in `GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker` in Xamarin.Forms, is there any other way to fetch data?

Comment: I want to upload Video to `YouTube` from Account from the Application.